# Can I defeat Arino in the game's credits?

Tags: retro-game-challenge

I finally got around to beating "Retro game challenge", and the credit screen includes a minigame where you fly a small spaceship on the bottom screen and can shoot energy bolts at Arino, located on the top screen. Arino, in turn, pelts you with various D-pad shaped projectiles.

I thought this was just a cute addition, but after hitting Arino enough he changed color and became more agressive, which led me to believe you can actually win this minigame.

Is it possible to completely defeat him before the credits are over? If so, what are the effects of such a victory, other than feeling good about yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, according to [Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/939911-retro-game-challenge/faqs/51726):

> =ENDING= [E]
>
> After completing all games, you'll get a final award, and the fourth
>   option on the main menu, Sound will be unlocked. During the credits
>   there will be a mini- shooting game in which you can shoot Arino's
>   head by pressing A & B. If you beat him he'll say something, but doing
>   so takes a LOT of shots. His head will change colors as he takes
>   damage.